# Webpack and Angular 2: Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, webpack, babeljs

I have the following set up an Angular2 app. If load the webpack server, the chunks work fine and the app is rendered. The final bundles will be used with .net mvc and I am simply adding the external script reference tags to the HTML file. Once I try loading the bundles in the .NET MVC framework I get the following error.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined`

I have tried creating one entry point with all dependencies as well and I still receive the error. What I am I missing or not understanding about the Webpack?

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var path = require('path');
var context = path.resolve( __dirname, '..');
var distPath = helpers.distPath(path.join(__dirname, '../'));

module.exports = {
    context: context,
    entry: {
        polyfills: './resources/polyfills.js',
        vendors: './resources/vendors.js',
        main:  './main.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, '../', "node_modules")
    },
    output: {
        path: distPath,
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
        pathInfo: true
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel" },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/, loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]' },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('components', 'root'),
                loaders: [ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap'), 'raw']
            },
            { test: /\.scss$/,  loader:'raw!sass?sourceMap!sass-resources'}
        ]
    },
    sassResources: [
        './components/root/main.scss'
    ],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['vendors', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("main.min.css")
    ]
};
```

Loading the scripts onto html:

I also tried playing with the order but no luck.

Comment: Besides the problem you've described I found some other issue: Why are you using `raw-loader` as the first loader for css files (remember they are called in reverse)? You should only use these two: `css-loader` and `style-loader`.

Comment: Thanks @dotcs I am doing a require('somesass.scss') in my component to inline my templates and styles in my component code. Raw is needed or it breaks.

Comment: @JoseCarrillo have you been able to fix this issue? if yes how?